# AWS event name for generated SSH keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there anyone that knows or can help me find the documentation that states the name of the event in CloudWatch whenever a new SSH key is generated in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event. You have to enable [CloudTrial trial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-and-update-a-trail.html), and detect [API call associated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html) with the creation of the keys in CloudWatch Events.

Comment: ah okay. Would you happen to know if the AWS documentation has steps that I could follow to do that?

Comment: @rand03 I added links to the answer.